# exercise 1.21 of chapter 1 of Revuz and Yor's

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

This is the exercise 1.21 of chapter 1 of Revuz and Yor's:

Let $X=B^+$ or $|B|$ where $B$ is the standard linear BM, $p$ be a real number $>1$ and $q$ its conjugate number ($q^{-1}+p^{-1}=1$).

1. Prove that the r.v. $J_p=\sup_{t\geq0}(X_t-t^{p/2})$ is a.s. strictly positive and finite and has the same law as $\sup_{t\geq0}(X_t/(1+t^{p/2}))^q$.
2. Using time-inversion, show that
   $$\sup_{t\geq0}(X_t/(1+t^{p/2}))\overset{(d)}{=}\sup_{u\leq1}\left(\frac{1}{1+u^{p/2}}\right)\left(\frac{X_u}{u^{1-p/2}}\right)$$
   and conclude that $E[J_p]<\infty$.
3. Prove that there exists a constant $C_p(X)$ such that for any positive r.v. $L$
   $$E[X_L]\leq C_p(X)||L^{1/2}||_p.$$
4. Let $L_\mu$ be a random time such that
   $$X_{L_\mu}-\mu L_{\mu}^{p/2}=\sup_{t\geq0}(X_t-\mu t^{p/2}).$$
   Prove that $L_\mu$ is a.s. unique and that the constant $C_p(X)=p^{1/p}(qE[J_p])^{1/q}$ is the best possible.
5. Prove that
   $$E[X_{L_1}|J_p]=qJ_p \text{, }E\left[L_1^{p/2}|J_p\right]=\frac{q}{p}J_p.$$

By the hints and the reference cited in the notes of the book, I almost solved this question. My only question is : In the proof of 4, I think I need $EL_\mu^{p/2}<+\infty$ (or $EX_{L_\mu}<+\infty$) firstly, but can't figure it out. Any help, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I think that if you post your solution on what you have done so far, it might attract more interest from the community (moreover your solution will be checked). Best regards.

Comment: Could you explain how did you get the first point?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, one needs to verify that $E[L^{p/2}_\mu]<+\infty.$ Consider the inequality 
$$
E[L^{p/2}_\mu]\leq 1+\sum^\infty_{n=0}2^{(n+1)p/2}P(2^n<L_\mu\leq 2^{n+1}).
$$
To bound the probability $P(2^n<L_\mu\leq 2^{n+1})$ few crude estimates are enough. The event $\{2^n<L_\mu\leq 2^{n+1}\}$ implies that the supremum of the function $t\mapsto X_t-\mu t^{p/2}$ is attained on $(2^n,2^{n+1}].$ Since this supremum is positive, it follows that for some $t\in (2^n,2^{n+1}]$ 
$$
X_t>\mu t^{p/2}.
$$
Further it follows that $X_t>\mu 2^{np/2}$ and, finally, 
$$
\sup_{0\leq t\leq 2^{n+1}}|B_t|>\mu 2^{np/2}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
P(2^n<L_\mu\leq 2^{n+1})\leq P\bigg(\sup_{0\leq t\leq 2^{n+1}}|B_t|>\mu 2^{np/2}\bigg)\leq 4P\bigg(B_1>\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}2^{(p-1)\frac{n}{2}}\bigg).
$$
Using tail estimates for the normal distribution it is easy to verify that the following series  converges:
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=0}2^{\frac{pn}{2}}P\bigg(B_1>\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}2^{(p-1)\frac{n}{2}}\bigg)<\infty.
$$
These estimates show that $L_\mu$ actually has all moments.